# How to implement telemetrics functionally in existing c++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I need to implement telemetrics functionally in the existing c++ code to analyze which methods are taking too much of Time to execute. Can log the time stamp in text file. Is it the correct way or is there any other way to proceed in c++. As I'm new to vc++, please provide your suggestions.

Comment: I usually use an external profiler rather than build it into the code. Visual Studio, if that's what the v in vc++ means, has a pretty decent set of profiling tools.

Comment: The customer have suggested not to use any third party tools.

Comment: I recommend adding that to the question. It's a pretty important detail.

Answer (score 4):

I developed the simplest code for C++ code self-profiling. It collects and displays statistics in the form of a call tree. You can modify it for your needs. 
To use, you only need to add `TRACE`macro in the analyzed block.

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

typedef double Time;
typedef unsigned int uint;

#ifndef FLATTEN_RECURSION
#define FLATTEN_RECURSION 1
#endif

class Profiler
{
   static Time getCurrentTime()
   {
      LARGE_INTEGER time;
      LARGE_INTEGER freq;
      QueryPerformanceCounter(&time);
      QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
      return 1.0 * time.QuadPart / freq.QuadPart;
   }

   struct Entry
   {
      Time fullTime_ = Time(0);
      const char* name_;
      uint started_ = 0;
      Time startTime_ = Time(0);

      Entry(const char* name) { name_ = name; }

      void start()
      {
         if (!started_) startTime_ = getCurrentTime();
         started_++;
      }

      void stop()
      {
         started_--;
         if (!started_)
            fullTime_ += getCurrentTime() - startTime_;
      }
   };

   struct CallTreeNode
   {
      const Entry& entry_;
      std::vector<CallTreeNode> childs_;

      CallTreeNode(const Entry& entry) : entry_(entry)
      {}

      CallTreeNode& addCall(const Entry& entry)
      {
         for (auto& itr : childs_)
            if (&itr.entry_ == &entry)
               return itr;
         childs_.push_back(CallTreeNode(entry));
         return childs_.back();
      }
   };

   std::vector<CallTreeNode*> callStack_;

   Entry rootEntry = Entry("root");
   CallTreeNode root = CallTreeNode(rootEntry);
   Time duration_;

   Profiler()
   {
      rootEntry.start();
      callStack_.push_back(&root);
   }

   void printTreeImpl(
      CallTreeNode& node,
      std::string& out,
      bool last = true,
      const std::string& prefix = "")
   {
      out += prefix + (last ? '\xC0' : '\xC3') + std::string("\xC4\xC4")
         + node.entry_.name_ + "  rate: " 
         + std::to_string(node.entry_.fullTime_ / duration_ * 100)
         + "% full time: " + std::to_string(node.entry_.fullTime_) + '\n';

      const int childsNum = (int)node.childs_.size();
      for (int i = 0; i < childsNum; i++)
         printTreeImpl(node.childs_[i], out, i == (childsNum - 1), prefix + (last ? ' ' : '\xB3') + "   ");
   }

   void forward(const Entry& entry)
   {
      callStack_.push_back(&callStack_.back()->addCall(entry));
   }

   void backward(const Entry& entry)
   {
      callStack_.pop_back();
   }

public:
   Profiler(Profiler const&) = delete;
   void operator=(Profiler const&) = delete;

   static Profiler& getInstance()
   {
      static Profiler instance;
      return instance;
   }

   static Entry newEntry(const char* name)
   {
      return Entry(name);
   }

   std::string printCallTree()
   {
      auto& inst = getInstance();
      inst.duration_ = inst.getCurrentTime() - inst.rootEntry.startTime_;
      inst.rootEntry.fullTime_ += duration_;
      std::string out;
      inst.printTreeImpl(root, out);
      return out;
   }


   class ProfilerAutoStopper
   {
      Entry& entry_;
   public:
      ProfilerAutoStopper(Entry& entry) : entry_(entry)
      {
         if (!entry_.started_ || !FLATTEN_RECURSION)
            getInstance().forward(entry_);
         entry_.start();
      }
      ~ProfilerAutoStopper()
      {
         entry_.stop();
         if (!entry_.started_ || !FLATTEN_RECURSION)
            getInstance().backward(entry_);
      }
   };
};

#define TRACE \
   static auto pflrEntry = Profiler::newEntry(__FUNCTION__); \
   Profiler::ProfilerAutoStopper autoStopper(pflrEntry);
```

Key ideas used:

1. Main profiler class is singleton.
2. A service object `ProfilerAutoStopper` is used to automatically start and stop the timer when entering and exiting the block. This eliminates multiple start / stop errors and handles exceptions correctly.
3. The `std::vector<CallTreeNode*> callStack_` stack and `CallTreeNode` tree  structures are used to construct the call tree.

## Using

```
void foo()
{
   TRACE;
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
}

void recursive(int level)
{
   TRACE;
   if (--level) recursive(level);
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5));
}

void bar()
{
   TRACE;
   foo();
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
}


int main()
{ 
   {
      TRACE;
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         foo();

      recursive(10);
      bar();
   }
   std::cout << Profiler::getInstance().printCallTree() << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

## Out

```
└──root  rate: 100.000000% full time: 0.191205
    └──main  rate: 99.971599% full time: 0.191150
        ├──foo  rate: 62.788339% full time: 0.120054
        ├──recursive  rate: 31.276141% full time: 0.059801
        │   └──recursive  rate: 31.276141% full time: 0.059801
        │       └──recursive  rate: 31.276141% full time: 0.059801
        │           └──recursive  rate: 31.276141% full time: 0.059801
        │               └──recursive  rate: 31.276141% full time: 0.059801
        │                   └──recursive  rate: 31.276141% full time: 0.059801
        │                       └──recursive  rate: 31.276141% full time: 0.059801
        │                           └──recursive  rate: 31.276141% full time: 0.059801
        │                               └──recursive  rate: 31.276141% full time: 0.059801
        │                                   └──recursive  rate: 31.276141% full time: 0.059801
        └──bar  rate: 11.446139% full time: 0.021886
            └──foo  rate: 62.788339% full time: 0.120054
```

With FLATTEN_RECURSION 1

```
└──root  rate: 100.000000% full time: 0.190720
    └──main  rate: 99.944164% full time: 0.190614
        ├──foo  rate: 62.658680% full time: 0.119503
        ├──recursive  rate: 31.347459% full time: 0.059786
        └──bar  rate: 11.477065% full time: 0.021889
            └──foo  rate: 62.658680% full time: 0.119503
```